# Fastest way to find integer coefficients for an integer valued polynomial

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math, polynomials

Be `p(x) = a1 + a2 x^2 + ... + an x^(n-1)` a polynomial so that all the coefficients `a1, ... an` are integer valued. Now, I am going to sample `n` polynomial values `yi = p(xi)` with all `xi` integer valued. This means that, in turn, all the `yi`s will be integer valued as well.

Now, given the set of `(xi, yi)`, I want to get back my `a1, ..., an` coefficients. I checked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). It says that the most straightforward way to get the coefficients is to solve the Vandermonde matrix associated to my sample.

However, it looks like this is not the most performing way to do such a thing. It says that there are properties of the Vandermonde matrix that make it possible to achieve a solution with `O(n^2)` time complexity rather than the usual `O(n^3)` Jordan elimination algorithm. I was wondering how those algorithms work and if they can be used working only with integers.

Comment: This question really belongs on the math SE site.

Comment: I thought that being related to algorithms I should have put it in here. Should I close this one and ask the same thing over there?

Comment: The explicit formula for the inverse of the Vandermonde matrix could be a way to go: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde's_Matrix

Comment: You could use Newton interpolation to find a polynomial with rational coefficients, then multiply with the least common multiple of the denominators.